# "Do", "make" or "of the" in a question

Tags: prepositions

I am not sure which of the following sentences are correct:

> What is the most common mistake that players do?
>
> What is the most common mistake that players make?
>
> What is the most common mistake of the players?

Comment: This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. Questions that do not show prior research are considered [off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistakes are *made*.
So your second sentence is the correct one.

> "**Making** mistakes is a lot better than not doing anything." -
>   Billie Joe Armstrong

And see [here](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/keywords/making_mistakes.html) for many more examples.